# VBa and Excel : sum up highlighted cells value from specific item number and then subtract to cells value from other table and display in next column

Tags: excel, vba

I am learning excel and VBa and I force with following trouble, I would like to sum up  highlighted Qty cells from right column(G) (where item number and start date are equal from left table for same item number) and then subtract to QTY from left column(B) for the same item number and finally display these results in column(K) next to highlighted item number. The tables are dynamic. I hope that’s is clear what I want to do.I try to sum up Qty in column G for highlighted item and then subtract to Qty in first column for the same item number and display in column(K) but is not working.

[image: Tables]

```
Sub check()
Dim lastData, lastData1 As Variant
Dim item1, item2 As Variant
Dim endD1, startD1, endD2, startD2 As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim ii As Integer
Dim countQ As String

'This will find "." in the date and replace it with "/" which is neccessary before to find a macht
Cells.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

lastData = Sheet7.Cells(Sheet7.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
lastData1 = Sheet7.Cells(Sheet7.Rows.count, 6).End(xlUp).row

'Loop through  tables
For i = 3 To lastData
  item1 = Cells(i, 1).value
  startD1 = Day(Cells(i, 3).value) & Month(Cells(i, 3).value) & Year(Cells(i, 3).value)
  endD1 = Day(Cells(i, 4).value) & Month(Cells(i, 4).value) & Year(Cells(i, 4).value)
   For ii = 3 To lastData1
      item2 = Cells(ii, 6).value
      startD2 = Day(Cells(ii, 8).value) & Month(Cells(ii, 8).value) & Year(Cells(ii, 8).value)
      endD2 = Day(Cells(ii, 9).value) & Month(Cells(ii, 9).value) & Year(Cells(ii, 9).value)
      If item1 = item2 And startD1 = startD2 And endD1 = endD2 Then
      highlight (ii)

      End If
Next ii
'Compare Data from first table (column A,C) and from second table (column F,H)and then substract to column
countQ = 0
If item2 = Cells(J, 6).Interior.Color = 65535 Then
    If startD2 = Cells(J, 6).Interior.Color = 65535 Then
       If item1 = item2 And startD1 = startD2 Then
          countQ = countQ + Cells(i, 7).value
          Cells(i, 11).value = countQ - Cells(i, 1).value


       End If
     End If
End If
Next i
End Sub

Function highlight(ByVal x As Integer)
    Range("F" & x & ":J" & x).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Not working? Please describe the expected output and your output

Comment: Your date formats look messed up. From the dates in the tables, I conclude that the format you use is `DD/MM/YYYY` (ex. 31/12/2019). However, many date entries are left aligned while others are right aligned. If you have not set the cell alignments as such, the left aligned might be caused by Excel not understanding the entries as dates. Or that they were entered as text. Anyway, you should make sure the dates are correctly formatted and entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to me your code shuold be this (explanations in comments):

```
Option Explicit ' <-- use this to force variables explicit dimensioning

Sub check()
' all variables must be dimensioned with its own type: unspecified types default to Variant
    Dim lastData As Variant, lastData1 As Variant 
    Dim item1 As Variant, item2 As Variant
    Dim endD1 As Variant, startD1 As Variant, endD2 As Variant, startD2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ii As Long
    Dim countQ As Long ' <-- you need it a numeric variable!

    'This will find "." in the date and replace it with "/" which is neccessary before to find a macht
    Cells.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    lastData = Sheet7.Cells(Sheet7.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastData1 = Sheet7.Cells(Sheet7.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop through  tables
    For i = 3 To lastData
        item1 = Cells(i, 1).Value
        startD1 = Day(Cells(i, 3).Value) & Month(Cells(i, 3).Value) & Year(Cells(i, 3).Value)
'        endD1 = Day(Cells(i, 4).Value) & Month(Cells(i, 4).Value) & Year(Cells(i, 4).Value) ' as per your wording, you don't seem to need endDate comparison

        countQ = 0 ' reset the second table Qty counter
        For ii = 3 To lastData1
            item2 = Cells(ii, 6).Value
            startD2 = Day(Cells(ii, 8).Value) & Month(Cells(ii, 8).Value) & Year(Cells(ii, 8).Value)
'            endD2 = Day(Cells(ii, 9).Value) & Month(Cells(ii, 9).Value) & Year(Cells(ii, 9).Value) ' as per your wording, you don't seem to need endDate comparison
            If item1 = item2 And startD1 = startD2 Then ' And endD1 = endD2 Then ' as per your wording, you don't seem to need endDate comparison
                highlight ii
                countQ = countQ + Cells(ii, 7).Value ' update the second table qty counter
                Cells(ii, 11).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value - countQ ' subtract the current second table qty counter form first table qty and place it in coumn K of current second table row
            End If
        Next    
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi guys, its really amazing how you assist to explain all problems and it improve my knowledge

Comment: @Vl111, you are welcome. If my answer solved your question you may consider marking it as accepted. thank you